# unable to pass null value in json

Tags: jquery, json

JQuery:

```
        var Arr = new Array()
        var Selected = null;
        if ($('#chk').is(':checked')) {
            var List = $('#sellist option:selected');
            $.each(List, function(index, item) {
                Arr.push($(this).val());
            });
            Selected = Arr.join(',');
        }
```

I have to pass `Selected` as a json parameter.When check box is checked `Arr` is not null so code work fine but when `Arr` is null or empty i am unable to pass as a parameter. I use `""` instead of `null` but unable to solve the problem. How to handle this type of situation. Thanks.

Comment: Quite ambiguous question. You talk about some checkbox and at the same time you perform a selector over a dropdown list.

Comment: @Darin Ya if check box is checked then only selected value is push in array else  `var selected` is empty or null.This is my situation.Thanks.

Comment: You mention something about passing the selected variable as JSON. Could you explain to what you need to pass it and how you are passing it more precisely? Are you doing AJAX or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understend where is the problem, becuase if i do:

```
var Selected = null;
var object = { selected: Selected};
console.log(object);
```

i have no error, i have just an object with a property that has a null vale. Maybe you are doing something wrong when you create your object or maybe i am missing something.

EDIT - if the problem is the you must send it through ajax afterwards you can simply skip the parameter if is null an then check if the parameters exist server side or you could assign it the value `false`

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply.I solve it to pass value `var Selected=0` instead of `null`.Its a war between asp.net and jquery using webmethod.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pre-select the select box first before you get a value from the `$('#sellist option:selected');` selector. You may insert it before the `var List = $('#sellist option:selected');` code.
`